# Rails.application.database_configuration error with Rails 5.1 + Nginx + Phusion_Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a server with Rails 5.1, Phusion_Passenger and Nginx.

When I start the server with just Phusion_Passenger, all is good:

```
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /project/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /project/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
Problems? Check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/troubleshooting/
===============================================================================
[ N 2017-09-26 15:13:06.4195 8753/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:374 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
```

When I try to start and access the same instance with Nginx as the overlay, I get the following error:

```
App 8129 stdout: 
App 8129 stdout: 
[ E 2017-09-26 15:06:26.4848 1774/T1l age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /project: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: e18b79ab
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-YkowRo.html
  Message from application: Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  (erb):13:in `<main>'
```

It seems that when you load the rails app with Nginx, it cannot access the "Rails" object.

Comment: Are you passing the DB details using environment variables? If yes then did you specify those in your nginx config?

Comment: Nothing is refined as a environment variable. Stock standard config/database.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Passenger does not have a default environment set in the passenger.conf. Added this variable and it fixed the problem.

```
passenger_app_env development;
```

Comment: Note this is obviously only correct for development. In production you should use the `production` env which is the default for nginx integration.